# $(this).append() appends to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to have a 2x2 table where each cell when hovered turns into another 2x2 table, similar in fashion to koalastothemax.com . This works by

1. Making the hovered cell invisible
2. Appending a 2x2 table inside of it, marking the new cells as "new"
3. Resizing the cells marked as "new"
4. Unmarking the new cells

The first hover even works well, the cell turns into a smaller 2x2 table. However upon hovering over a newer cell part of the newly appended table, despite the $(this).append, it appends the table to the parent element (the cell that was initially hovered over)

Here's the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/0c64tt2q/

Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Cursor enters a visible cell
    $('td.standard').mouseenter(function () {

        //Make the cell invisible
        $(this).removeClass('standard');

        //Find the dimensions of the cell
        var dimension = $(this).width();

        //Insert 2x2 table into cell
        $(this).append("<table><tr><td class='standard new'></td><td class='standard new'></td></tr><tr><td class='standard new'></td><td class='standard new'></td></tr></table>");

        //Resize the new cells and remove the 'new cell' marker
        $('.new')
            .css({
                'width': dimension / 2,
                'height': dimension / 2
            })
            .removeClass('new');
    });
});
```

Comment: you probably want to be using event delegation. see my updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/azoapw2e/ and the doc on delegation here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mouseenter event is only set to the first set of table cells. Try attaching the event this way instead so that the event handler is "live" and will be valid for new elements too.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", 'td.standard', function(event) {

  //Make the cell invisible
  $(this).removeClass('standard');

  //Find the dimensions of the cell
  var dimension = $(this).width();
...
```